# python re.sub with a list of words to find

Tags: python, regex, list

I am not too familiar with RE but I am trying to iterate over a list and use `re.sub` to take out multiple items from a large block of text that is held in the variable `first_word`.

I use `re.sub` to remove tags first and this works fine, but I next want to remove all the strings in the `exclusionList` variable and I am not sure how to do this.

Thanks for the help, here is the code that raises the exception.

```
exclusionList = ['+','of','<ET>f.','to','the','<L>L.</L>']

for a in range(0, len(exclusionList)):
      first_word = re.sub(exclusionList[a], '',first_word)
```

And the exception :

```
first_word = re.sub(exclusionList[a], '',first_word)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 245, in _compile
raise error, v # invalid expression error: nothing to repeat
```

Comment: first_word = re.sub(exclusionList[a], '',first_word)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat

Comment: Junuxx, thanks for the help. I simply added '\+' to the exclusionList and it works now. Since the list is static this is a fine solution for me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The plus symbol is an operator in regex meaning 'one or more repetitions of the preceding'. E.g., `x+` means one or more repetitions of `x`. If you want to find and replace actual `+` signs, you need to escape it like this: `re.sub('\+', '', string)`. So change the first entry in your exclusionList.

You can also eliminate the for loop, like this:

```
exclusions = '|'.join(exclusionList)
first_word = re.sub(exclusions, '', first_word)
```

The pipe symbol `|` indicates a disjunction in regex, so `x|y|z` matches x or y or z.

Comment: Aologies if I was confusing. That part works. I removed it from the code to make it more clear where the problem lies and included the exception as a comment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @EnglishGrad: No, the plus symbol is the cause of the exception. Compare `re.sub('+', '', 'foo')` with `re.sub('\+', '', 'foo')`. The first gives the exception you're seeing, the second does not.

Comment: Junuxx, I see what you are saying now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The basic form of your program is correct, so I suspect any problem you are having has to do with the regexes you are using. '+' by itself is an invalid regex, you'll need to escape it using '\'.

From a usage point, Python allows you to specify that a string should not do any backslash escaping, so that you don't have to litter your regexen with '\\' when you just mean '\'. The syntax for this is a leading "r", as in `r'\+'`, which is what you should replace the first item in your exclusionList with.

If you are looking to extract the words "to", "the", etc. then you also want to make sure you are extracting whole words, and don't accidentally extract the "to" in "tooth", or the "the" in "other". Add "\b" to specify a word boundary to prevent this: `r'\bto\b'` and `r'\bthe\b'`.

Lastly, `for a in range(0, len(exclusionList)):` is more simply written by just iterating over the list itself: `for exclusion in exclusionList:`.

Comment: Good point about the word boundaries, but I disagree with your suggestion about the loop.

Comment: The `for a in range(0,len(seq)): do something with seq[a]` form is limited in a couple of ways. `seq` must support `len()` and `[]` access, so you would not be able to pass anything other than a list or tuple (sets and dicts would fail - no `[]`, as well as generators or generator expressions - no `len`). Two functions are called, `range` and `len`, and in 2.x Pythons, `range` actually builds an intermediate list object containing all of the values. Using `for` with a range of list indexes is an idiom carryover from C or BASIC; iterators are more efficient and more widely applicable.

Comment: That is all true, but not what I meant. In this case the for loop and its overhead are entirely unneccesary, see my answer.